# Get a div element background color to modify a text color

Tags: javascript, function, colors, background-color

[image: exemple]

Hi Everyone :)

As on my example in image I have several div elements representing the colors and I wish that by clicking on them the text entered by the user changes color

```
 <label id="color" for="coloris">Coloris :<span class="haut">V</span><span>V</span></label>
  <div id="coloris">
<div class="dot" title="RAL 9018 - Blanc Papyrus" style="background-color:#d4dbd9" onclick="changeColor('#showtext')">
    <input type="radio" value="RAL 9018 - Blanc Papyrus" name="RAL">
    </div>
    <div class="dot" title="RAL 9016 - Blanc Signalisation" style="background-color:#f6f8fa" onclick="changeColor('#showtext')">
    <input type="radio" value="RAL 9016 - Blanc Signalisation" name="RAL">
    </div>
       <div class="dot" title="RAL 9011 - Noir Graphite" style="background-color:#212123" onclick="changeColor('#showtext')">
    <input type="radio" value="RAL 9011 - Noir Graphite" name="RAL">
    </div>
       <div class="dot" title="RAL 9010 - Blanc Pur" style="background-color:#f4f5ef" onclick="changeColor('#showtext')">
    <input type="radio" value="RAL 9010 - Blanc Pur" name="RAL">
    </div>
```

```
<script>
function changeColor(background){
  document.getElementById("showtext").style.color = document.querySelector(".dot").style.backgroundColor;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your changecolor function to take an element as parameter and change the text's color with the clicked element's background color like so:

```
    function changeColor(e){
        document.getElementById("showtext").style.color = e.style.backgroundColor;
    }
```

Then pass the clicked element to your changecolor function with the ***this*** keyword like so:

```
onclick="changeColor(this)"
```